# How to click on a div drop down menu

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click on a link that's in a drop down menu. First, I will explain how it works. When you mouse over the link called help, the drop down menu appears.  From this menu, you can then select the User options "link". I found the mean under a `div` tag, but I can't get it to work. I have tried these lines of code, but they do not work. My question is how do I click on the User settings link.

```
e.frame(:name, "content").frame(:name, "main").div(:id, "menu4").link(:index, 0).click
e.frame(:name, "content").frame(:name, "main").select_list(:text, "Help").select("User Settings")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get an error (e.g. `Unable to locate element`)?  It looks like Text - User Settings is in a `<td>` with an `onclick` attribute.  But it's tough to tell from the screenshot.  Issues like this are often due to `<iframes>`, dynamic content that hasn't finished loaded, etc.

Comment: If it's a dropdown menu, I would assume you got this error:
`WebDriverError': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError)

You probably need to click on the parent div(:id => "menu4") first, and then click td(:text => /User Settings/).  If you list the error that you're getting, it would be much easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was a silly mistake but the answer is

```
e.frame(:name, "content").frame(:name, "main").div(:id, "menu4").td(:index, 1).click
```

Even though it is a link, the container is a table, so the moral of the story is always use the tag.

Comment: it is not a link, there is no <a> tag anywhere in that table.  Also if the menu contents are subject to change, then going on the content of the cell you want might be less brittle, and create code that makes your intent a bit more obvious to someone else (or yourself) when you are working with it down the road  `e.frame(:name, "content").frame(:name, "main").div(:id, "menu4").td(:text, "User Settings").click`

Comment: I came here to post this ^.  Chuck's suggestion will save you or someone else a lot of frustration later!